# How to make a generic extension method in Java like in C#?

Tags: java, c#, generics

I want to implement a generic extenstion method in java like i did in c#.

Here are my C# Codes:

**DataRecordExtensions.cs**

```
public static class DataRecordExtensions
{
    public static T Get<T>(this IDataRecord record, string fieldName, T defaultVal = default(T))
    {
        object o = record[fieldName];
        if (o != null && !DBNull.Value.Equals(o))
        {
            try
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(T));
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
        return defaultVal;
    }
}
```

Here is how i use it the DataRecordExtensions method:

**CountryRepository.cs**

```
public class CountryRepository : ICountryRepository 
{
    // ... here are some code not relevant to understand my problem

    public IEnumerable<Country> LoadCountries()
    {
        List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();

        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            string sqlTxt = "SELECT * FROM tab_Countries ORDER BY SortID";

            using (SqlCommand readCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlTxt, sqlConnection))
            {
                SqlDataReader countriesReader = readCmd.ExecuteReader();


                while (countriesReader.Read())
                {
                    Country c = new Country();

                    c.CountryCode = countriesReader.Get<string>("CountryID");
                    c.Country = countriesReader.Get<string>("Country");
                    c.SortID = countriesReader.Get<int>("SortID");

                    countries.Add(c);
                }

                readCmd.Dispose();
                countriesReader.Dispose();

            };
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        return countries;
    }
}
```

Like you can see, i use **countriesReader.Get< string >("CountryID")**
Now i want to use something like this with Java. How can i make a extention method like this to use in Java or are there any alternatives?

Comment: Did you search anything about java generics?

Comment: Alternatives include Groovy and Kotlin.

Comment: I don't believe Java has an equivalent to extension methods.

Comment: @Omore yes i searched for java generics but i did not found any solution and like juharr say i also think there is not equivalent from C# in Java. But anyway, i don't understand all this negativity in stackoverflow, if you can not offer me any solution, why you assume i have not searched or did any effort myself? Stackoverflow is a great plattform, but some people here really need to change their mindset. I even think you did not undestand the question or problem.

Comment: @Rep I just ask you it's doesn't depend on how I am thinking about your question but anyways you reply me after 5 days. also you should read other comments too. thanks

Answer (score 1):

With Java, you can also call a method like this.

```
private FileConfiguration config = ....
public <T> T getFromConfig(String path) {
    return (T) config.get(path);
}
```

In which it could be called like

```
String bar = Foo.<String>getFromConfig(Some.File.Path);
```